# In Excel Graph, how do I transform the macro to select multiple columns of data as x and y to stop just below a blank row?

Tags: excel, vba, graph

[Starting off-manually selecting the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzvFw.jpg)

Ok. I will explain what I am trying to achieve... I have a chart of data wth which I want to plot a line graph with markers using data in columns D and E excluding the heading as points on the x axis data and columns G to L as points on the y axis. I was using recording macro to see the code to manually select data as shown in step1. Although the last row is 32 as stated in the current macro, I would want to change that so it will be able to work out the last row itself ...using the end(x1down) function.

[codes obtained by recording macro when inserting line graph with markers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxhNh.jpg)

```
Range("D2:E32,G2:L32").Select
Range("G2").Activate
Source:=Range("Sheet1!$D$2:$E$32,Sheet1!$G$2:$L$32" )
```

So how to achieve my objective by changing these 3 lines of code above? At the moment, the range is specified as D2:E32, G2:L32 because I manually define the last row. So how can I rewrite this to include the .endx1down to cover the multicolumns in both part ie...D2 to E32 and G2 to L32. Also would this be the same for the line Source:=....etc..

Answer (score 0):

Something along the following lines should do the trick ...

```
Dim Ws as Worksheet, R as Range, LastRow as long
Set Ws = ' some worksheet, maybe the active worksheet, I don't know the context.
Set R = Ws.Range("G2") ' for example - any row inside your data except the last. Any column containing contiguous columns down to the one you want.
LastRow = R.End(xlDown).Row
```

Comment: The line that starts LastRow ... above sets LastRow to the number of the row reached via R.End(xlDown). You are welcome to use the code, but you will need to adapt it to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine this is for use within the ChartWizard. In most cases, the way to do this is to create 2 ranges, one for the value (y) axis and one for the category (x) axis of your chart. Call them Rx and Ry. Then you take their union (call it Ru) and feed that as source:=Ru ...

```
Dim Rx as Range, Ry as Range, Ru as Range
Set Rx = ' some range for the x axis.
Set Ry = ' soem range(s) for the value axis.
Set Ru = Union(Rx, Ry)
With YourChart
    .ChartWizard Source:=Ru, ' etc. etc
End With
```

Hope this is what you want ...